# swift ColorPicker is triggered twice even when one color is selected only once

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, colors

I need to create an array of colors created/selected by the user by using `ColorPicker`, bind it to a `@State var tempColor` variable, and append `tempColor` to the array of selected colors, but the problem is the behavior is unstable. Specifically, sometimes the same color is added twice to the array even when a color is selected/pressed once.

I added some logic to check for duplicate colors before adding the selected color to the array but still a color is added twice to the array. This behavior occurs like 80% of the time when `ColorPicker` is pressed and a color is selected.

Any idea to solve the problem please?

my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State var createdColors = [Color]()
@State var tempColor: Color = .white

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ColorPicker("selected color", selection: $tempColor)
            .padding(10)
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            HStack {
                ForEach(createdColors, id: \.self) { col in
                    Circle()
                        .fill(col)
                        .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                        .padding(10)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    .onChange(of: tempColor) { _ in
        if createdColors.contains(tempColor) {
            print("we have the color already \(createdColors.count)")
        } else {
            createdColors.append(tempColor)
            print("adding new color \(createdColors.count)")
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Similar questions have been asked in the past. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66524025/swiftui2-picker-onchange-firing-twice-need-value-before-change-and-after and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63694325/onreceive-firing-twice-swiftui

Comment: I will check them out, thanks!

Comment: I did try both solutions but still have the same problem, any other suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

Give the system a little break.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var createdColors = [Color]()
    @State var tempColor: Color = .white
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ColorPicker("selected color", selection: $tempColor)
                .padding(10)
            Text("Currently ^[\(createdColors.count) item](inflect: true)")
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                HStack {
                    ForEach(createdColors, id: \.self) { col in
                        Circle()
                            .fill(col)
                            .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                            .padding(10)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: tempColor) { newColor in
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                if createdColors.contains(newColor) {
                    print("We have the \(newColor.description) already. Total: \(createdColors.count)")
                } else {
                    createdColors.append(tempColor)
                    print("Adding new color to \(createdColors.count)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There are better ways to resolve the issue. This is just a quick fix.

Comment: I will test it and get back to you for any updates and will vote if it works, thanks @Paul!